# Ruby in android

Tags: ruboto

I want to start a project in android in ruby.
I already use rails n did many project by using ruby on rails.
can anyone suggest me what to install in my com? My com has os linux.I want to run 
my android project in my com. pleaze help me .

Answer (score 2):

You can find a guide to get started with Ruboto here:

- https://github.com/ruboto/ruboto/wiki/Getting-started-with-Ruboto

If your setup is not covered there, here are the needed steps for the base installation.

First you need to install Java, ANT, and the Android SDK:

- http://java.sun.com/
- http://ant.apache.org/
- http://developer.android.com/index.html

Then you need to install a Ruby implementation and the ruboto gem:

- http://www.ruby-lang.org/

  [sudo] gem install ruboto
- http://jruby.org/

  jruby -S gem install ruboto
- http://rubini.us/

  Not sure about this one.

You can get help with using Ruboto on the mailing list, the IRC channel, or by filing an issue in the tracker as described on the home page:

- http://ruboto.org/